# Wordpress: How to add a post request after the user confirmed the email and activated the account?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, plugins

Respecting all the wp pattern, security and update.
Maybe there is already a plugin than do this action.. I could not find any.

I see there is an hook `USER_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE` that I could use, I would like to know what's the general approch to edit wp code. Shall I create my own plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in functions.php file in your theme

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'action_after_user_register', 10, 1 );
function action_after_user_register( $user_id ) {
    //Do Some Things
}
```

I had success with this function when link to Odoo system.